# Can we load a Label(similar to a function) into our namespace for calling later?

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line

I am currently learning batch, I have learnt we can create a **label** which to me seems to work similar to a function in other languages.

However very quickly my batch file is becoming cluttered.

Is it possible for me to move my **label** into another *.bat* file and load it into my main *.bat* file for later use(NOT instant use)

I am thinking of something like the following *(Psuedocode)*

**main.bat**

```
include funcCopy.bat
include funcDeleteDir.bat

@echo "hello Stackoverflow"
...
@call funcDeleteDir "C:\Windows"

@echo "hi again"
...
@call funcCopy "C:\Program Files" "C:\Users"
```

**funcMove.bat**

```
:funcCopy
XCOPY /Y "%~n1" "%~n2"
goto :EOF
```

**funcDeleteDir.bat**

```
:funcDeleteDir
@RD /S /Q "%~n1"
goto :EOF
```

I have managed to achieve instant use and moving each function to another file, However its messy as I must include a call to the function from within its own batch file, Also because of this it is executed instantly upon inclusion, Something I do NOT want. This instant use is as follows

**main.bat**

```
@call funcCopy     @call funcCopy "C:\Program Files" "C:\Users"
```

**funcMove.bat**
    @call funcCopy "%~n1" "%~n2"

```
:funcCopy
XCOPY /Y "%~n1" "%~n2"
goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is "no"...the batch language does not support that.

But, you can do what you're suggesting without needing an `include` for the other files or needing labels in those files.

From `main.bat`, you can just `CALL` the other `.bat` file:

**main.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
call funcDeleteDir.bat "C:\Windows"
```

**funcDeleteDir.bat**

```
@ECHO OFF
RD /S /Q "%~n1"
```

Comment: This appears to be a cleaner way rather than using labels.

Comment: Yeah, you only need to use labels when you want functions and want/need to keep everything in one file.